# PCB fab questions: Surface finishes and reasonable source for a single board

Tags: pcb-fabrication

I've designed a unique Stylophone-type keyboard. I've prototyped it on Masonite with copper foil tape. Now, I'd love to get a slick PCB fabricated. It's a large board, but I feel like, as a hobbyist, I'm just a complete annoyance to the places I've been contacting for quotes, because, well I don't know everything, and I've got questions.

My main question, at the moment, is about surface finishes. I plan to solder an array of tuning trim pots and fixed resistors to the board myself. But, the board has very large 'key' pads. It would be nice if the copper pads had a finish that prevented the copper from oxidizing. But, am I correct in thinking that "Lead-free HAL,' for instance is a *solder* finish that I would NOT want or need on those key pads?

Any suggestions for congenial, reasonable fab shops that have no board minimum would also be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please explain what a key pad is.  HAL (lead-free too) is a fine, easy to hand-solder finish that also has long shelf life before soldering.  The downside is that the surface can be rougher than other finishes (sometimes a problem for the smaller pitch parts).  Recommending vendors is likely off-topic here.  However, overseas vendors (pool vendors) should be able to accommodate tiny/single quantities.  If you're stateside, then the typical rule is that if you buy 1, you might as well buy 16 for the same price.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stylophone - it's just a bare pad that's touched with a stylus. Anything but bare copper would work. Hard gold suggested for connoisseurs :)

Comment: Explorer - Hi, (a) You can't ask meta-questions in the question text, so they have been removed. If you are having trouble using the site, even after reading the [tour] & the [help], there is an [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7931) and you can ask for advice on our [meta] site. (b) Don't ask *new* questions in comments, nor by extending the question by editing. Only *clarifications* of the original question are allowed as edits. Don't invalidate existing answers by editing the question (e.g. if someone extends a question in an edit, then existing answers will then seem incomplete).

Comment: (continued) (c) You can ask new questions as a follow-up, *but* wait until one question is finished (ideally by you [áccepting](/help/someone-answers) an answer, to clearly indicate that the topic is effectively finished). Don't have multiple "open" questions at the same time, especially if there is any overlap between them, as that can cause duplicated effort so it generally annoys people. Duplication between questions is one of the allowed reasons for a question to be closed e.g. by user votes. (d) Please note that shopping / recommendation questions are [off-topic](/help/on-topic). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These days, the go-to places for prototype PCB fabrication are JLCPCB, PCBWAY, Rushpcb, Expresspcb, or similar online-process sites. If there's no way to quote and submit the job online, don't bother - it won't be cost effective for them to take your business.

Any online PCB fab shop will have an explanation of available surface finishes. You *do not* want bare copper - it will oxidate/corrode rather quickly and will look pretty bad, with fingerprints etched into the surface etc. ENIG (electroless nickel-under-gold) would be a nice finish - a bit more expensive than HA[S]L, but hey - shiny! :)

Comment: It looks like "hard gold" is available too (I only looked at PCBWay, presumably the others have prety much the same options), which gives the opportunity to have a thicker layer of gold, which I imagine would be better for wear when used with a stylus moving over it.

Comment: The board is large. The keyboard area is 5" x 13.75." Gold over that expanse will cost a fortune, won't it? But, I'm not going to be soldering to those pads, just running contact devices over them that fit on my index fingers, made from aluminum cigar tubes. There's no way to add a photo to these threads? I was going to put up a photo of my prototype. The main keys are T-shaped and wrap around each other. Sharps and flats are rectangular and available both above and below the T-shaped pads.

Comment: Do I need a "solder paste" layer in the Gerber files for a board finish? I'm working in OsmondPCB and I have only output drill files, copper layers 1 & 2, mask layers 1 & 2, and silkscreen. Or do the ordinary mask layers cover it?

Comment: Never mind about the solder paste layer question above. I figured that out. My OsmondPCB design document outputs solder paste layers. I had tossed those files, because I didn't think I needed them. Looks like I've got a stencil for my 'key pads,' but, oddly perhaps, it doesn't include plated through holes.

Comment: @Explorer the solder paste layer is used to make a stencil for silkscreening solder onto the board. If you're doing hand assembly you don't need it.

Comment: Hard gold would be several hundred bucks for a board that big, but it would look gorgeous. Perhaps you can make a couple special editions and sell them for cost of gold :)

Comment: Yes, I think from some additional reading, ENIG is a good suggestion for a finish for my large Stylophone-type keys, to prevent oxidation—which I imagine would increase resistance, and thus, de-tune the thing, or make it not work altogether. Anyone want to advocate against that? It's affordable, via PCBWay's online quote, although they haven't seen the files yet. I'm waiting to hear back, to find out if anyone there looks at the files, or if the process is entirely automated. I'm terrified to hit the checkout button, go to Paypal, send money, and just pray that I've done everything correctly.

Comment: BTW, SamGibson, what's a meta-question?

Comment: @Explorer - Hi, (a) "*what's a meta-question?*" It's a question about your question e.g. an admin topic - not a real part of the technical question. In your case, you had added to your question: "*Should I be adding more questions/info here?*" That is asking a question about how to ask a question - hence "meta question". (b) Please use `@`replies in comments. More info is on [this page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43019) from the FAQ. `@`replies help to address your comments. Normally, I would not have seen your comment (and so not replied) due to it missing the `@`. Thanks and welcome.

Comment: Sorry if thanks are inappropriate on this site, but I just finished placing an order with PCBWay for my first PCB and it's a HUGE deal to me. Thanks, especially to @Kuba hasn't forgotten Monica. I went with ENIG on the finish. And thanks, Sam, for all the site tips.

Comment: *Stylophone-type keys, to prevent oxidation—which I imagine would increase resistance, and thus, de-tune the thing* If the design gets detuned by oxidation on the keys, it wasn't done right to begin with. A "stylophone" with tuning elements connected directly to the key pads is going to be problematic in all sorts of ways. There needs to be a separate key contact detection circuitry that switches pitches independently of exact stylus resistance. The stylus can have a conductive polymer tip and its resistance can change with pressure. That'd be used for dynamics etc.